# Battery never charges upto 80% instead of 100%

Tags: laptop, troubleshooting, battery, charging

My vaio battery charges only upto 80%. Why is that so? It also tends to discharge too fast providing less working time. How to proceed to obtain 100% charge?

Comment: Can you provide more details about your system? How old is the battery?

Comment: If you get a replacement, here's a link for you to bookmark, learn everything you'll have to know about proper treating a laptop battery: http://www.batteryuniversity.com/

Comment: My battery is only 5 months old.. In the beginning it used to get charged upto 100% bt then weeks ago i noticed this problem. Did calibrate it bt no improvement.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens with older batteries when they are simply unable to hold a full charge.

Is it an old battery, say more than a couple of years old?  If so, you might want to think about replacing it with a shiny new one.

[Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Troubleshoot-battery-problems) have a troubleshooting page for laptop batteries which mentions this.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off the battery care function of your vaio, this function limits the battery charging to 80% in order for the battery to have a longer useful life.

Answer (score 1):

Since you had it for only 5 months, you can take your laptop to SonyStyle store for checking on the battery. The warranty should still be good & you will probably get a new battery & put this issue behind.

Comment: Well am from mauritius and got my laptop from america! So its kinda difficult for that! Anyway thanks i'll try callibration.

Answer (score 0):

Go into vaio control center, under the battery tab, turn off the battery care function. Then it will charge up to 100%.