# Samsung laptop, Stop charging at 80% and says Plugged in but not charging

Tags: windows, laptop, battery

After I upgraded Windows 7 to Windows 10 in my Samsung laptop, the AC charging stop at 80% and show "plugged in, not charging".

Then I downgraded back to Windows 7, problem still exists.

I have tried :

1. Shut down
2. Remove battery
3. Boot up on AC power
4. Uninstall the ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery driver
5. Shut down
6. Reinsert battery
7. Reboot

Still cannot fix the problem. I am wondering whether it is a configuration problem?

Comment: Related: [Battery never charges upto 80% instead of 100%](http://superuser.com/questions/111610/battery-never-charges-upto-80-instead-of-100), and [How does limiting a laptop battery's full charge to less than 100% extend its battery life?](http://superuser.com/questions/502328/how-does-limiting-a-laptop-batterys-full-charge-to-less-than-100-extend-its-ba)

Answer (score 2):

Check your BIOS/UFI settings.  There is an option to extend the life of your battery by not charging it all the way back to 100%.  Additionally, if you have the Samsung Settings program installed, you may also be able to toggle it in there as well.